# opencv use graphics card by default

Tags: graphics, opencv

im doing circle detection on vdeo feed and i am finding that opencv plays my video back extremely slow. I was wondering if opencv makes use of the graphics card or just the CPU. is there a way to tell opencv to use the graphics card??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OpenCV can be compiled with GPU support using CUDA. Some methods like SURF point extraction have a gpu implementation. See [here](http://opencv.itseez.com/trunk/modules/gpu/doc/gpu.html) for more information.

In order to use the GPU support, you need to have CUDA installed and compile the OpenCV source code with the USE_CUDA flag set in CMake.